# Limit Results using Google Geocode API

Tags: google-maps-api-3, bing-api, geocode

I am working on a project which requires the use of the free Google Geocoding API. I need to use the results of the Geocoding API query to validate the query itself and make sure all the fields are correct.

I have been trying to see if there is an option parrallel to the Bing api `maxResults` parameter, but cannot seem to find anything in the documentation. The `maxResults` parameter limits the number of addresses returned and therefore makes the job take substantially less time.

Here's the Bing API documentation that contains information about the maxResults parameter. (ctrl+f):
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701714.aspx

And the overview of the Google Geocoding API can be found here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro

Answer (score 2):

Your post is quite confusing since you tagged it as `google-maps-api-3` which is technically for **[Google Maps Javascript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding)** but the documentation you provided is for **[Web Services Geocoder API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro)**.

But to answer your question, right now this feature is not available for the **Web Services Geocoder API** and there's no work around to limit the maximum results.

Limiting the returned results for **Javascript API Geocoding Service** is also not available but there is a work around where you can limit the number of results that you will be displaying on the *client-side (front end)*. You can do this simply by **not** looping through every result and just limiting the loop to the number that you want.

Here's a portion of the sample code where I did a `for-loop`, and set a variable `len` (for length).

```
var s_markers = [];
var map;
function initialize() {
  var currentarea = { lat: 14.5393988, lng: 121.0521586};
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 2,
    center: {lat:0,lng:0},
    disableDefaultUI: true
  });

  var address = 'google maps'; // just used google maps since it returns multiple results
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address },function(results, status) {
    // var len = results.length;
    var len = 2; //declare here the number of wanted result
    for (var x=0; x<len; x++){
      var pos = results[x].geometry.location;
      map.panTo(pos);
      var s_mark = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: pos,
        title: results[x].formatted_address,
        map: map
      });
      s_markers.push(s_mark);
    }
  });
}
```

Originally I used here `var len = results.length` to display all the results as marker. But to limit the results displayed, you can set this as `var len = 2` or `var len = 1`. The original number of returns here is `3`.

You may see the full code here: http://jsbin.com/nagadis/edit?html,js,output

> However, if you want this feature where you can limit the number of results, the best thing you can do about this is to file a **Feature Request** in [Google Issue tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/)

Hope this helped!