# Google Maps Api: how to limit returned result?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I want to do reverse geocoding using url like:
=> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452

But the returned results is usually more than i wanted, sometimes more than 15.

How to limit it just 1 result?

I read the guide here and found nothing:
=> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/requests-reverse-geocoding

Comment: possible duplicate of [Limit Results using Google Geocode API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50396591/limit-results-using-google-geocode-api)

Answer (score 1):

Related question: [Limit Results using Google Geocode API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50396591/limit-results-using-google-geocode-api)

What you may want is either `result_type` or `location_type` [optional_parameters](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/requests-reverse-geocoding#optional_parameters).

From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/requests-reverse-geocoding#optional_parameters):

> **result_type** — A filter of one or more address types, separated by a pipe (|). If the parameter contains multiple address types, the API returns all addresses that match any of the types. A note about processing: The result_type parameter does not restrict the search to the specified address type(s). Rather, the result_type acts as a post-search filter: the API fetches all results for the specified latlng, then discards those results that do not match the specified address type(s).The following values are supported:
>
> - `street_address` indicates a precise street address.
> - `route` indicates a named route (such as "US 101").
> - `...`

> **location_type** — A filter of one or more location types, separated by a pipe (|). If the parameter contains multiple location types, the API returns all addresses that match any of the types. A note about processing: The location_type parameter does not restrict the search to the specified location type(s). Rather, the location_type acts as a post-search filter: the API fetches all results for the specified latlng, then discards those results that do not match the specified location type(s). The following values are supported:
>
> - `"ROOFTOP"` returns only the addresses for which Google has location information accurate down to street address precision.
> - `"RANGE_INTERPOLATED"` returns only the addresses that reflect an approximation (usually on a road) interpolated between two precise points (such as intersections). An interpolated range generally indicates that rooftop geocodes are unavailable for a street address.
>   `"GEOMETRIC_CENTER"` returns only geometric centers of a location such as a polyline (for example, a street) or polygon (region).
>   `"APPROXIMATE"` returns only the addresses that are characterized as approximate.

Adding `&location_type=ROOFTOP` to the [example request](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&location_type=ROOFTOP) yields 3 results (when a key is added).

adding `&result_type=street_address` to the [example request](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&result_type=street_address) yields 1 result (when a key is added).

Comment: This is unrelated answer. The question is how to limit the number of result. Not how to filter the result based on type. The OP doesn't care about the type. He ask about how to limit the number of result of any type.

Comment: Then the answer is the duplicate/related question, "you can't"